# My Django/Python logger is updating a rotated log instead of the main log

Tags: python, django, logging

On my dev system, which has exactly the same RotatingFileHandler setup as our production systems, the primary log is the one that is always updated:

```
mylog.log    <==== This one is updated.
mylog.1.log  <==== Rotated file, not updated.
mylog.2.log  <==== Rotated file, not updated.
```

This is how I expect log rotation to work.

In our production setting, however, I have noticed lately that it is "mylog.2.log" that is being updated. I can't explain or reproduce this behavior in development. File permissions on all log files are exactly identical, as is ownership and group.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your production runs multiple processes while your dev env is single process, right? In that case, you will need to find another way. Send for example the logs to syslog and let the syslog rotate your logs. Or let every process to log to separate file.

Comment: Right now, our production system runs a single process. Our current peak is 2-3 concurrent users. I am moving us to a load-balanced, 5-worker-per-node topology soon, but right now, there is only one process logging.

Comment: Is there something else that could rotate the logs? If something else renames a file while it is still open by a process, such process continues to append to that file until it is really closed.